# Flip text input fields between elements, including user-created value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to flip the input fields between two div elements. However, if a user enters text into the fields, the text disappears after the flip happens. Is there a way to make sure this value attribute is flipped too? Thanks.

Javascript:

```
function Flip ()
{
    var oldslave = $('div.slave').html();
    var oldmaster = $('div.master').html();
    $('div.slave').html(oldmaster);
    $('div.master').html(oldslave);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="master">
    <input type="text" name="master" id="master" size="42">
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="Flip()" value="Flip">
<div class="slave">
    <input type="text" name="slave" id="slave" size="42" class="slavefield">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method like this:

```
function Flip() {
    var oldslave = $('div.slave input').clone();
    var oldmaster = $('div.master input').clone();
    $('div.slave').html(oldmaster);
    $('div.master').html(oldslave);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MaESg/

There is also another variant to achieve the same without using clone:

```
function Flip() {
    $('.master').find('input').appendTo('.slave').prev().appendTo('.master');
}
```

This one is preferable because appending (moving) nodes much more effective than recreating.

http://jsfiddle.net/MaESg/1/